# How to make UILabel fade out instead of showing the three dots ellipsis on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uilabel

If the contents of a `UILabel` don't fit into the available space, iOS shows automatically the three dots. I think it looks much nicer if instead of the dots a gradient is applied which fades out the content the close it gets to the right edge.
Is the something built in in iOS or do I have to implement it all myself?

Answer (score 1):

please try this..

```
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
label.numberOfLines = 1;
CGSize size;
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {

    size = [label.text sizeWithAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:label.font, NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
} else {

    size = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font];
}

if (size.width > label.frame.size.width) {

    CAGradientLayer *gradLayer=[CAGradientLayer layer];

    gradLayer.frame = label.layer.bounds;

    [gradLayer setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)([UIColor blackColor].CGColor), (id)([UIColor clearColor].CGColor),nil]];
    gradLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.75, 0.0);
    gradLayer.endPoint=CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);
    label.layer.mask = gradLayer;

} else {
    label.layer.mask = nil;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That is not available by UIKit.

You will have to change the labels's `layer.alpha` on an `as-you-type` basis (meaning in `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` for `UITextField` or `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text` for `UITextView`, or whatever are you using, searchbar etc.)

Or, as **David Rönnqvist** suggested, you can add an overlay to it if you don't want your entire label to be hidden.
Or also you can change your `textColor` with a color with more/less transparency. There's a few ways to do it ...

Comment: The alpha property in itself won't do it, it changes the alpha of the entire label. You would have to mask or overlay the end of the label to only fade the end.

Comment: whatever suits him best - either the entire `UILabel` or adding something else as you said.

Comment: I think I'm looking for a way to add a sublayer or mask layer to the content view of the UITableViewCell. However I get pretty weird results until now.

Comment: have you tried setting `cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.7];` and adjusting the `alpha` value ?

Comment: I have now added a a CALayer to the cell's content view which is white opaque. Left of that I have a CAGradientLayer which fades from white alpha 0 to white alpha 1. This covers the dots. However, it has a hardcoded with, so I'm not entirely happy with it.